# Decompress .zip file using Poco/Zip Library

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

After compress successfully(using Poco lib), I found that I can able to decompress a .zip file which contains files but not sub-folder

My decompress block of code :

```
struct UnzipStruct unzipObject;
unzipObject.unzip(source, target);
```

Here is MyUnzipStruct :

```
struct UnzipStruct
{
    void unzip(std::string source, std::string target) {
        fs::path sourcePath = fs::path(source);
        std::ifstream inp(sourcePath.string(), ios::binary);
        fs::path targetPath = fs::path(target);
        Poco::Path targetDir(targetPath.string());
        Poco::Zip::Decompress dec(inp, targetDir, false, true);
        // if an error happens invoke the ZipHandlingLib::onDecompressError method
        dec.EError += Poco::Delegate<UnzipStruct, std::pair<const Poco::Zip::ZipLocalFileHeader, const std::string>>(this, &UnzipStruct::onDecompressError);
        dec.decompressAllFiles();
        dec.EError -= Poco::Delegate<UnzipStruct, std::pair<const Poco::Zip::ZipLocalFileHeader, const std::string>>(this, &UnzipStruct::onDecompressError);
        inp.close();
    }

    void onDecompressError(const void* pSender, std::pair<const Poco::Zip::ZipLocalFileHeader, const std::string>& info)
    {
        std::cerr << info.second << "\n";
    }
} unzipObject;
```

Is it a bug of Poco or Did I do something wrong? Because I can extract a zip file by 7z(which contains sub-folder). The exception I get is AssertionViolationException from Poco.

Comment: Look at the example how to set up an error handler for `dec.EError` https://pocoproject.org/docs/ZipUserGuide.html

Comment: @S.M. I'm just getting errors near `Ziptest`, do you know which file to includes or which methods do I need to implement to fix it?

Comment: `ZipTest` is just a test class name, you should implement the class `ZipTest` (or another name) with the method `onDecompressError` (or another name) and pass object of the class and pointer to the method to the `poco::Delegate` constructor.

Comment: @S.M. yeah, I just edited my post, I have come through that but still can't extract the zip file yet.

Comment: I think it's better to report the issue on Poco bug tracker https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues

Comment: @S.M. yeah, I already post the issue there. Thanks a lot, mate.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the fact that you are passing keepIncompleteFiles=true to the Decompress constructor?  What is the actual Assertion string you are getting?  Usually there is something printed.  Do you have permission to create the directories?